# Unable to run acceptance test in IntelliJ after creating a new Mule Connector

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, mule

I'm having difficulty running the default mule connector test in IntelliJ 12.1.4 after I create a new Mule Connector

First I create a new mule connector using:

```
mvn archetype:generate
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.mule.tools.devkit
-DarchetypeArtifactId=mule-devkit-archetype-generic
-DarchetypeVersion=3.4.0
-DarchetypeRepository=http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/
-DgroupId=org.testPackage
-DartifactId=myArtifactId
-Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
-DmuleVersion=3.4.0
-DmuleModuleName=myModuleName
-Dpackage=org.testPackage
-DarchetypeRepository=http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases
```

Then I run "mvn clean install", which is successful:

```
= Testing: testFlow
...
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.098 sec - in org.testPackage.myModuleNameModuleTest
```

I import the project in to IntelliJ ("File/Import Project..."), then rebuild the project ("Build/Rebuild Project...") successfully.

If I run testFlow() in IntelliJ ("Right-click on myModuleNameModuleTest, then select "run testFlow"), I get the following error:

```
= Testing: testFlow
[09-08 14:09:03] WARN  XmlBeanDefinitionReader [main]: Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mymodulename/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/mule-mymodulename.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:96)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:380)

org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Line 13 in XML document from URL [file:/Users/sporcina/git_repos/test/myArtifactId/target/test-classes/mule-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'mymodulename:config'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":description, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context":property-placeholder, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":global-property, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":configuration, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":notifications, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-agent, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-security-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-exception-strategy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-flow-construct, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":sub-flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-model, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-interceptor-stack, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-filter, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transformer, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":processor-chain, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":invoke, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-intercepting-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-queue-store, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-processing-strategy}' is expected. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
```

Any idea what's causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the artifacts (code, schema, ...) generated by DevKit, which is in `target/generated-sources/mule`, is on your project's classpath path.

Comment: It is.  The module settings shows that the path "target/generated-sources/mule " is defined as a Source Folder.